# trying to print arrays in java need assistance

Tags: java, arrays

I have been taking a class in Java Programming for the past couple of weeks and the previous projects have been simple like calendars or random number generators. This project however is very difficult and there is a small part (step 5) I do not have a grasp on. In this project I have to create an array printer using these steps:

> 1.) Start a program in a class named ArrayPrinter. Ignore the main method for a moment.
>
> 2.) In your class, create a static method named printArray with one parameter of type int[] named arr. Inside this method, do the following.
>
> a. Keep all of your output on one line using System.out.print() until directed to use println().
>
> b. Display an opening square bracket character.
>
> c. Loop through the array that was passed into the method. Display the values in the array. Add a comma and a space after every value except for the last one.
>
> d. Using System.out.println(), display a closing square bracket character.
>
> 3) In your main method, create the following array. Pass the reference to this array to the printArray method, run your program and verify that it works as expected.
>
> 4) In your main method, add a blank println() statement after the method you just made.
>
> 5) In the class, create an overloaded static method named printArray with one parameter of type int[][] named arr. Inside this method, do the following:
>
> a. Using println(), display an openeing square bracket character.
>
> b. Loop through the two-dimensional array that was passed into the method.
>
> i. First use System.out.print() to display two space characters.
>
> ii. Every element of this two dimensional array that your are looping through is a one-dimensional array of int. Call the other printArray method and pass to it each one-dimensional array in the two-dimensional array.
>
> c. Using println(), display a closing square bracket character.

Here is the code I have so far, could you please direct me to my error or any ways to improve upon my code? What I don't understand is exactly how to loop through the two-dimensional array that was passed into the method. Did I do it correctly and if not how can I fix my error?  :

```
public class ArrayPrinter {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printArray(new int[] {5, 6, 7, 8}); 
    println("");

}
public static void printArray(int[] arr) {
       int size = arr.length;
        System.out.print("[");
        for(int i=0;i< size; i++){
            System.out.print(arr[i]);
            if(i<size-1){
                System.out.print(",");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }
public static void printArray(int[][] arr) {
        int size = arr.length;
        println("[");
        for(int i=0;i< size; i++){
            System.out.print(" ");
            if(i<size-2){
                System.out.print(",");
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: @Aominè I have improved upon my question to go into detail as to what I don't understand. Could you help me?

Comment: You need a nested loop to go through a two-dimensional array.  That is, a loop inside a loop.

Comment: @DM I have never heard about a nested loop. It was nowhere in the lesson I was learning. What does it look like?

Comment: @Scar change your `printArray` call from the main method to this --> `printArray(new int[][] {{5, 3, 7, 8}, {5, 657, 567, 8},
                {5, 234, 7, 8},{5, 23, 7, 8},{5, 456, 7, 6}});` as you're told to invoke the two-dimensional array first, you can then finish it off by calling the `printArray` that takes a one-dimensional array from within the `printArray` that takes the two-dimensional array. I would have provided an answer but I am quite busy at the moment , sorry.

Comment: Lets say you have 2d array like `int [][] arr = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} }`. If you use `arr[0]` you will get `{1,2,3}` array, if you use `arr[1]` you will access `{4,5,6}`. You can think of it as accessing rows in table. Now since you can access such rows which are 1d arrays combine them with method which prints such 1d array (just like you are instructed in `ii.` point).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the space: `System.out.print(", ");` instead of `System.out.print(",");`

Also, create a bi-dimensional array, for example:

```
printArray(new int[][] {new int[] {6, 7, 8, 9}, new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4}});
```

Inside `printArray(int[][])`, you should call the `printArray(int[] arr)` to accomplish the point number 5.

Just call the `printArray(int[] arr)` from the **for** cycle you created inside `printArray(int[][] arr)`, and pass each one of the elements of your bi-dimensional array (somtehing like `printArray(arr[i])`).

Try to understand the modifications and improve the output print. Happy learning!

Comment: Up-vote for not providing full code. So many people fail to realize that purpose of homework is not to get working code, but to learn how to solve problems needed to create one.

Comment: @rperes I implemented your suggestions and my code is working except for one thing. Next it tells me to insert a two dimensional array which I did 'printArray(new int[][] {new int[] {2, 4, 6, 8}, new int[] {8, 7, 9, 1}, new int[] {3, 5, 1, 2},});'.  It says my expected results should be
[5, 6, 7, 8]

[

[2, 4, 6, 8]

[8, 7, 9, 1]

[3, 5, 1, 2]

]

but instead I get: 
[5, 6, 7, 8] 

[ 

[ 

2,


4,

6,

8,

]
 
[
 
8,

7,


9,

1,

]
 
[
 
3

5

1

2

]
 
]

Comment: You have **System.out.println("]");** but you should have a **System.out.print("]");**. If a new line is needed you should implement it outside the **printArray** method.

Comment: And on **printArray(int[][] arr)**, the condition to add a coma it's not correct, it should be **i<size-1**.

Comment: @rperes The formatting on this website is weird so I cannot tell the difference between what I have and what I should have. I also had already corrected the comma condition

Comment: You have System.out.print **ln** ("]"); but you should have a System.out.print("]");. <-- without the ln (new line)

Comment: @rperes oh ok i get it. But my other problem is for the third set of numbers I do not get any commas for some reason on the third set of brackets for new int[][]

Comment: Can you please write the output result you are getting?

Comment: There is also another problem I noticed the output I am getting is [5, 6, 7, 8]
[
[2, 4, 6, 8, ]
[8, 7, 9, 1, ]
[3512]
]. 
I should be getting:[5, 6, 7, 8]
[
[2, 4, 6, 8]
[8, 7, 9, 1]
[3, 5, 1, 2]
]. 
There is also another problem I noticed the output I am getting is [5, 6, 7, 8]
[
[2, 4, 6, 8, ]
[8, 7, 9, 1, ]
[3, 5, 1, 2]
]. 
The second problem is after the last number in each set I am still getting the comma and space afterwards. I believe the best solution to this is a two conditional if statement, but I do not know what my second condition would be.

Comment: Check the order of the statements, the **printArray...** should be before the 'coma conditional' statement.`printArray(arr[i]);
            if(i<size-1){
                System.out.print(", ");
            }`

Comment: @rperes I am pretty sure it is cin the correct order right now my code is 
`for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){System.out.print("[");for (int j=0; j< arr[i].length; j++){System.out.print(arr[i][j]);if (i<size-1){ System.out.print(", ");  }`

Comment: I see, the method `printArray(int[] arr)` does all the job, so you don't need to have those 2 **for** cycles. This should be enough for your `printArray(int[][] arr)` method: `public static void printArray(int[][] arr) {
        int size = arr.length;
        System.out.print("[");
        for(int i=0;i< size; i++){
            printArray(arr[i]);
            if(i<size-1){
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
        }
        System.out.print("]");
    }`